# Transitive actions on sets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

Does there exist a transitive action of $S_4$ on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ ?

I would say no, because the cardinality of our set is bigger than $4$, but I am not sure how to prove this. My suggestion would be that we can’t obtain the element $5$ with the cycles of $S_4$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume such an action exists, then using the class equation, one has: $$5=|\{1,2,3,4,5\}|=|\mathfrak{S}_4.1|.$$
(a transitive action has only one orbit)

Besides, using orbit-stabilizateur lemma, $|\mathfrak{S}_4.1|$ is a divisor of $|\mathfrak{S}_4|=24$, a contradiction, since none of the divisors of $24$ are equal to $5$.

*Reminder.* Let $X$ be a finite set and $G$ be a group acting on $X$, the class equation states that: $$|X|=\sum_{[x]\in X/G}|G.x|.$$

Comment: So is it enough to say that the orbit of a transitive action has only one orbit and is different from 5 ?

Comment: The points are that there is only one orbit under a transitive action, the cardinality of the orbits must be divisors of the cardinality of the group and the distincts orbits form a partition of the set.

Comment: But 1 is a divisor of the cardinality of our group here no ?

Comment: Yes, but $1$ is not equal to $5$, don't forget the last point : the distincts orbits form a partition of the set (class equation). $\mathfrak{S}_4.1$ is a notation for the orbit of $1$ under $\mathfrak{S}_4$.

Comment: Understood, great thank you ! So simply, a transitive action would only work for a set of cardinality 1 ?

Comment: No, this is not true. For example $\mathfrak{S}_n$ acts transitively on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.